# 'to - infinitive' structure

Tags: to-infinitive

Could you please explain the grammatical structure for the sentence below? There are 3 uses of 'to' in this sentence, and I have no idea how to interpret them.

Full sentence

> As with interpersonal relationships, the net benefit that people need TO achieve TO decide TO stay in a community depends upon the alternatives that are available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence is a little awkward, but we can parse the meaning more easily by breaking it into smaller phrases.

> The net benefit (that people need to achieve) (to decide to stay in a community) depends upon the alternatives.

In the first phrase, **that people need to achieve** is a relative clause describing **the benefit**.

The second phrase starts with **to** to express purpose.  In this case, the purpose of achieving the net benefit, is so that the people can decide to stay.

Comment: I totally understand it. Many thanks! Just saying that it is about user behavior on online communities.